# How can I translate "cleavage"?

Tags: translation

What is an idiomatic way to say *cleavage* in Esperanto?

Answer (score 5):

First I had to google for a translation to my native language to understand what a cleavage is. Out of curiosity I checked what Google Translate gives. It gave me *intermama fendo*, which describes right away the matter! A further googling revealed that this time Google seems to have got it right.

*Intermama fendo* shows one of the strengths of Esperanto, an expression that clearly describes a matter instead of resorting to too specific words.

Comment: Bele respondita! Tute klara kaj trafa.

Comment: Laŭ mi `mamfendo` normale sufiĉus. Mi sugestas tion laŭ la modelo de kunmetaĵoj iel `mamzono`, `mamtenilo`. `brustofendo` estus alia eblo.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the word *dekoltaĵo*. *Dekolti* is the way of cutting a top so that it reveals the top part of the chest and *dekoltaĵo* is that part of the clothing, or by extension the shape that it forms on a person with breasts.

Comment: [*Dekoltaĵo*](https://vortaro.net/#dekolta%C4%B5o) **nur** rilatas la vestaĵon, tio [kontroleblas en Tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com/?s=6010de8f46909). La demandinto celas la korpan parton. [Ekzemple en la angla](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cleavage): *The dress is cut low enough to reveal a lot of cleavage.*

Comment: En la Reta Vortaro ĝi ja diras ke la vorto povas temi pri la korpa parto: “dekolataĵo […] korpa parto tiel nudigita”. La demandinto fakte ne precizigis kion ri celas. Mi pensas ke en la angla kiam oni diras “cleavage” oni celas la formon kreitan pro la vestaĵo, kaj tial kutime estus pli bone revortumi la frazon uzante la vorton “dekolt-” kiu pli klare implicas ke la vestaĵo havas rolon. Ekzemple se oni volas traduki “she has a beautiful cleavage”, oni povus diri “ŝi havas belan dekoltaĵon” kaj oni komprenus ke oni ŝatas rigardi ŝian korpon, kaj ne simple volas rigardi la robon sen la homo ene.

Comment: Mia komento enhavas ligilon al sufiĉe norma difino de "cleavage" (Merriam Webster). Bonvolu kontroli tiun kaj ankaŭ [tiun ĉi, de Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cleavage). Temas pri korpoparto. Angle oni povas neformale uzi la korpoparton kaj celi la veston, sed ne inverse (neniu korpo havas "low cut neckline"). La vorton *dekoltaĵo* oni uzas en kunteksto de [tajlo](https://vortaro.net/#tajli_kdc). *Dekoltaĵo* estas laŭ mi *tajlcela malkovra eltranĉo en vesto.* se ĝi validus por korpoparto, laŭ la difino en PIV, ĝi ankaŭ validu por ŝultroj, nuko kaj dorso.